# iPhone app within an app?

Tags: iphone

Can an iPhone app be made to contain another app? I am not talking about the URL scheme method or the iTunes AppStore linking method. I mean is there a way to enclose an app inside another app and switch between them at will?

Comment: In theory there's a limited possibility to do this (although switching back and forth is likely to not work and Apple is likely to reject you). The big question is: what is it that you're trying to accomplish? Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: theres an app showing information of a city. Inside this app I wanna show some other city information but as a different app. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do a different app for that? Implement a corresponding view controller and present that. You're trying to hack the system in a bad way and you would defeat the usual UI paradigms that a user knows. Plus your app would likely get rejected.

Comment: Allright point taken, but i need separate apps for different cities. I need to give the user an option to download other city apps in one app. So how do I do that? I am guessing the only way is the openURL iTunes trick.

Comment: Either you make an app for each city, then you have to distribute them each on their own through the app store. Each would have its own URI scheme but you would need to handle the fact that a user might not have the city app installed that you want to call (show a dialog with an iTunes link or something). Or you're providing just one app and have it download the data for each city (if you want money, In-App Purchase is the way to go here).

Comment: Your reasoning for separate apps still doesn't make sense. Multiple custom views accomplishes the scenario you are describing.

Comment: Well I WAS thinking of a master database with separate cities as tables or Core Data entities but In App Purchase is a good idea too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make this an answer: in theory, it would be possible to embed an app inside your "parent" app bundle and call its executable. However, you would likely not be able to switch between them on the fly and parameter passing would be tricky (for example, the custom URL scheme is likely to not work). There's also a very high risk that Apple would reject this and you would have thus wasted a lot of time (and thus money).

The usual way to switch between two app is by using a [custom URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). You would then need to have separate apps, each to be downloaded via App Store. You would need to handle that an app is not installed (you can check via [canOpenURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a)) and, for example, show a dialog with an App Store link that asks the user to download the missing app.

Maybe the better way is to have just one app that is able to handle all your data but make the user pay via In-App Purchase for each additional content to be made available. You could either ship all the data right with your app or have each part to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

As per **Apple Developer Guidelines** & **SDK Documentation** such thing is not possible which is the limitation.**And this may be because of security reasons only.** Whereas in other platform like Android the same thing is possible.

Below are the possible ways in which you can launch other applications from your native app.
Examples of some of the key applications **in iPhone** that you can launch via URL are:

1. Launch the Browser
2. Launch Google Maps
3. Launch Apple Mail
4. Dial a Phone Number
5. Launch the SMS Application
6. Launch the Browser
7. Launch the AppStore

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do the same thing for over a month but i found that its not possible .

Comment: so in short, the only way to link apps is by URL schemes or AppStore NSURL method right?

Comment: yes. its not possible. But the same can be done if its a mac application

Answer (score 0):

Nah, not really. You can make HTML5 apps within a native iOS app, as long as you only use HTML and JS Core and nothing else. You may also not provide any in-app apps that deal with gambling, lottery and charity. You're also not allowed to use any store-like interface and if you're in-app apps have any microtransactions (e.g. game coins and such things), you are forced to use the iTunes in-app purchase system and pay the 10-30% Apple tax.
Snapchat did a smart move by enabling 3rd party devs to implement Snapchat ads to their apps (e.g. watching a short video to get coins in a game).

Apple really doesn't want us to create our own ecosystem. They wanna keep us small by having these really strict rules.

Read 4.7 in Apple's official guidelines for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#third-party-software

//EDIT:
I hope I get your point correctly. Do you mean apps running within one app like in WeChat? They are called super apps btw. You can't find much on the web but maybe this will help:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/wechat-mini-programs/